# How does the ESPRESSO Echelle spectrograph fold the spectrum so nicely?

Tags: observational-astronomy, spectroscopy, data-analysis, instruments

The CBC News Technology and Science Q&A [This ESPRESSO machine doesn't make coffee but scans the skies for habitable planets](http://www.cbc.ca/news/technology/espresso-habitable-planet-search-1.4437598) includes a nice description of [ESPRESSO](https://www.eso.org/sci/facilities/develop/instruments/espresso.html) (Echelle SPectrograph for Rocky Exoplanet and Stable Spectroscopic Observations) and links to the YouTube video [Echelle SPectrograph for Rocky Exoplanet and Stable Spectroscopic Observations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vugHl.jpg).

There's something really amazing about the way that the spectrogram has been folded so nicely on to this image. Is this what it looks like on a 2D detector? (*sans colour* of course)

**I see what looks like eight distinct sections**, and a really nice spacing between adjacent lines otherwise. **How is this accomplished?**

Click or open the image in a new tab for full size view (it's worth it; 1.8 MB, 1738x2530)

[image]

**above:** Frame grab from the [video](https://youtu.be/pPkVv3D8lS8) at about `00:55`. Recorded with Python using [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43159565/3904031), then extracting frames using [this script in Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/43531/5334). Click or open in new view for full size - it's worth it.

[image]

**above:** What an Echelle spectrogram "normally" looks like (again with added color). From the really interesting University of Virginia [ASTR 3130 (Majewski) Lecture Notes](http://faculty.virginia.edu/ASTR3130/lectures/spectroscopy/spectrographs.html).

Comment: Not sure what you are asking - how to produce an echellogram or why Espresso uses 8 detectors?

Comment: @RobJeffries I'm familliar with how "vanilla" cross-dispersion Echelle spectrographs work. If this really a mosaic of multiple detectors, then that information, along with a description of how the light is actually split among those detectors without significant loss of information would be a basis for an excellent answer. Are the bare silicon die just butted against each other, or are there kinfe-edge mirrors or prisms that cut the beam into sections perhaps? Thanks!

Comment: @RobJeffries Espresso doesn't use 8 detectors. It uses two 6kx6k CCDs. To answer your question: Espresso uses a dichroic to split the light at about 515nm on two seperate cameras / detectors. For a detailed answer see their optical design paper: https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Denis_Megevand/publication/235614227_Optical_design_of_the_ESPRESSO_spectrograph_at_VLT/links/0f31752f201987c9d3000000/Optical-design-of-the-ESPRESSO-spectrograph-at-VLT.pdf

Comment: @JulianS. OK that makes more sense - the single large gap along the middle would then be the space between them.

Comment: No, the vertical gap (and also the horizontal gaps) is an artifact from how they readout the detector / how the overscan region of the CCD looks like.  The real gap between the detectors is horizontally. They just stacked the two images on top of each other.

Comment: @JulianS. Could you construct a short answer?

Comment: @JulianS. I've added a bounty